# How to do searching on the basis of custom field with the help of Nutshell Api?

Tags: java

I have some custom field with contacts on Nutshell. Let's say `tf_id`, and I want to search the contact whose `tf_id=123` with the help of Nutshell API. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted to Nutshell support about this topic.Unfortunately Nutshell CRM does not provide searching on the basis of custom field.